# Material Ui divider error (The above error occurred in the <hr> component)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../style'
import messages from './message'
import withStyles from 'hoc/withStyles'
import withIntl from 'hoc/withIntl'
import sports from 'static/home/sports.png'
import compose from 'recompose/compose'
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider'
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
function Sports ({ classes, intl }) {
  return (
    <Divider>
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <div className={classes.box}>
            <h1>{intl.formatMessage(messages.sports)}</h1>
            <img src={sports} alt={'sports'} className={classes.img}/>
            <h2 className={classes.sports}>{intl.formatMessage(messages.sports)}</h2>
            <h3>{intl.formatMessage(messages.text)}</h3>
          </div>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </Divider>
  )
}

export default compose(withIntl(), withStyles(styles))(Sports)
```

> The above error occurred in the
>
> ---
>
> component:
>       in hr (created by Divider)
>       in Divider (created by WithStyles(Divider))
>       in WithStyles(Divider) (created by Sports)
>       in Sports (created by WithStyles(Sports))
>       in WithStyles(Sports) (created by InjectIntl(WithStyles(Sports)))
>       in InjectIntl(WithStyles(Sports)) (created by Content)
>       in div (created by Content)
>       in Content (created by WithStyles(Content))
>       in WithStyles(Content) (created by Information)
>       in div (created by Information)
>       in Information (created by WithStyles(Information))
>       in WithStyles(Information) (created by HomePage)
>       in HomePage (created by InjectIntl(HomePage))
>       in InjectIntl(HomePage) (created by Route)
>       in div (created by MainLayout)
>       in div (created by ElementWrapper)
>       in ElementWrapper (created by Element)
>       in Element (created by MainLayout)
>       in MainLayout (created by WithStyles(MainLayout))
>       in WithStyles(MainLayout) (created by mapProps(WithStyles(MainLayout)))
>       in mapProps(WithStyles(MainLayout)) (created by getContext(mapProps(WithStyles(MainLayout))))
>       in getContext(mapProps(WithStyles(MainLayout))) (created by Route)
>       in Route (created by PageRoute)
>       in PageRoute (created by Component)
>       in Switch (created by Component)
>       in Component (created by Application)
>       in Application (created by Connect(Application))
>       in Connect(Application) (created by lifecycle(Connect(Application)))
>       in lifecycle(Connect(Application)) (created by Connect(lifecycle(Connect(Application))))
>       in Connect(lifecycle(Connect(Application))) (created by InjectIntl(Connect(lifecycle(Connect(Application)))))
>       in InjectIntl(Connect(lifecycle(Connect(Application)))) (created by Route)
>       in Route (created by withRouter(InjectIntl(Connect(lifecycle(Connect(Application))))))
>       in withRouter(InjectIntl(Connect(lifecycle(Connect(Application)))))
>   (created by Chain)
>       in MuiThemeProviderOld (created by Chain)
>       in JssProvider (created by Chain)
>       in Router (created by Chain)
>       in IntlProvider (created by Connect(IntlProvider))
>       in Connect(IntlProvider) (created by Chain)
>       in Provider (created by Chain)
>       in Chain (created by Component)
>       in AppContainer (created by Component)
>       in Component
>
> React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the
>   error boundary you provided, AppContainer.

https://material-ui.com/api/divider/ -here is the link where you can check the API , I tried to use `Divider` component from `material ui` , but got this issue , why does it occur ? Above you can see snippet of code by which I want to use `Divider` and also error with all stack

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE: This answer applies to Material UI version <= 4. As of v5, MUI allows `Divider`s to have children. Thanks to Mosia Thabo for the correction.**

MUI latest version Divider: https://mui.com/components/dividers/#main-content

---

The Material UI `Divider` component is just a horizontal line, so it shouldn't have any children.

Instead of this

```
<List>
    <ListItem>
        <div className={classes.box}>
            <h1>{intl.formatMessage(messages.sports)}</h1>
            <img src={sports} alt={'sports'} className={classes.img}/>
            <h2 className={classes.sports}>{intl.formatMessage(messages.sports)}</h2>
            <h3>{intl.formatMessage(messages.text)}</h3>
        </div>
    </ListItem>
    <Divider absolute/>
</List>
```

try this:

```
<List>
    <ListItem divider>
        <div className={classes.box}>
            <h1>{intl.formatMessage(messages.sports)}</h1>
            <img src={sports} alt='sports' className={classes.img}/>
            <h2 className={classes.sports}>{intl.formatMessage(messages.sports)}</h2>
            <h3>{intl.formatMessage(messages.text)}</h3>
        </div>
    </ListItem>
</List>
```

Note the `divider` prop on `ListItem`, which automatically places a `Divider` line after the `ListItem`'s content.

MUI v4 Divider: https://v4.mui.com/api/divider/

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../style'
import messages from './message'
import withStyles from 'hoc/withStyles'
import withIntl from 'hoc/withIntl'
import sports from 'static/home/sports.png'
import compose from 'recompose/compose'
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider'
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'

function Sports ({ classes, intl }) {
  return (
    <List>
      <ListItem>
        <div className={classes.box}>
          <h1>{intl.formatMessage(messages.sports)}</h1>
          <img src={sports} alt={'sports'} className={classes.img}/>
          <h2 className={classes.sports}>{intl.formatMessage(messages.sports)}</h2>
          <h3>{intl.formatMessage(messages.text)}</h3>
        </div>
      </ListItem>
      <Divider absolute/>
    </List>
  )
}

export default compose(withIntl(), withStyles(styles))(Sports)
```